# For the life of me I cannot make a file-set argument the next to last one

Tags: python, filenames

I want to run something like:

`python command.py  -i -c  "f*.xxx" "search"`

This fine since "file-set" is not expanded" but:

`python command.py -i -c  f*.xxx "search"`

This is expanded so 
`sys.argv = ['command.py','-i', '-c', 'f1.xxx','f2.xxx','search']`

Why couldn't it be  `['command.py','-i', '-c', ['f1.xxx','f2.xxx'],'search']` ?

Since the "f*.xxx" is not accessible I have no way to know if 'search' is a file name and the real 'search' missing.  I want to print an error message that
says "Please use quotes".  And I must keep position this way and turning off
globbing is not an option. getopt and argparse do not solve this.
Thanks

Comment: I also want to add another optional argument which seems to cause issues in argparse.

Comment: I also want to allow single files (f1.xxx) as a valid file-set so I can't search for wildcards in sys.argv[3].

Answer (score 1):

It's your shell, not Python, that's doing the expansion. Python always sees a single flat list of arguments.

In case you want to parse arguments, which basically turns this flat list into a more complex data structure, you can use the `argparse` module, or use more extensive third party projects like `click`.

Comment: I know the shell is to blame, I just want a solution. I mentioned argparse in my question. So far, I haven't seen any code examples that are robust and work. Then add optional arguments, well forget it..

Comment: Something like this might work if I could only get "history" to run in Python:
try:   os.remove("hist") <br>
except OSError: <br>
   pass <br>
x=os.system("history 2 > hist") <br>
x=os.system("cat hist") <br>
f_h=open("hist","r") <br>
com_line=f_h.readline() <br>
print com_line <br>
:

Comment: "just wanting a solution" for a problem that's not clearly explained is not really gonna work...  you're conceptually mixing shell and python.

Comment: "not clearly explained ..."  I want to place an argument AFTER an argument that has been expanded by the shell. I don't think it can be done